# Why WhatsApp is suddenly unable to open any APK shared by users?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, apk

As of 13-11-18, I was sharing APK files on WhatsApp, for testing apps within a circle of people, with no problem whatsoever. But as of today, if I try to open an apk, I get an error toast saying:

> You may not have the proper app to view this content.

Did they change their policies and decided not to let people share APK files on their platform?

I don't use third party websites for sharing APKs, where mostly Chrome spooks most people saying that "This type of file may harm your device".

Comment: Open .apk file from file explorer (/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/) instead of WhatsApp. Or zip your apk file before sending over WhatsApp.

Comment: my friends are not so big on going so deep in their devices... how did it stop working...did the latest update come with a bug?

Comment: I don't think so any changes have been made related to this. Usually there is problem handling the proper content according to file type. Are you sure file is being sent with .apk extension? What version of Android your friends are using?

Comment: I am getting the same error since I tried for the first time... Install the apk through the file manager.

Comment: @IrfanLatif lollipop and above.. well it was working properly till now

Answer (score 4):

Well as per my understanding this is how files are opened from WhatsApp making use of file extensions:

- File type is determined from extension ([getMimeTypeFromExtension](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java#33)) and [intent.action.VIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_VIEW) is launched provided with file path `dat=` and file type `typ=`.
- If the file extension is not known, file is treated as [octet-stream](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java#117) mime type.
- List of preferred apps (`/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` which is built from user selected defaults and files at [/system/etc/preferred-apps/*.xml](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java#3290)) is checked for activities that can handle this file type.
- If there is only one app that can handle this mime type, that app (activity) is launched. You can see which app handles what mime type by:

  ```
  dumpsys package preferred-xml
  ```

  <sup>Use `adb shell` or one of `permission.DUMP` or `root` is required.</sup>
- If there are multiple apps (more than one matching activity for the given intent) available and no preferred app is already set, [ResolverActivity](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java#86) (from Android framework resources) is launched (not [intent.action.CHOOSER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER)) showing a dialog to select app (for `Once` or `Always`).
- If the file type is apk (typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive) and PackageInstaller is set to handle this file, `action.INSTALL_PACKAGE` is invoked.
- Now if Android version is Oreo or above and WhatsApp is updated, it would need [permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) to install unknown package. Once granted, app will be installed.

You can use logcat to view how this whole process goes on. Use `adb shell` or one of `permission.READ_LOGS` or `root` is required. You can share results here to help me and others understand where the chain breaks.

**Workaround:**
Make sure that files are sent and received with correct extension i.e. .apk. If WhatsApp is unable to handle downloaded apk file for any reason, use a File Manager. Explore to `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents` and install apk file.

**RELATED:** [Alternative “File Open” (not stack “DocumentsUi”) for WhatsApp?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210168/218526)

Comment: Hi, when I click the apk the error toast pops up with the following warning

I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/50743 typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x1} from uid 10072 on display 0

Comment: typ= application means whatapp can see the type of the file right?