# Is there a way to change the default file manager app?

Tags: file-system, file-management, files

I was wondering whether I could replace the file manager that comes with my phone with a 3rd-party app in a way that any app that needs file access, goes through the 3rd-party app to find the appropriate file. The only other similar question I could find here is left unanswered and I wasn't able to find anything online.

Comment: I don't think Android offers to set an app as a default file manager app (at the least not up to Android 8.x). Are you talking about [Documents Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) which helps you to pick a file through an app, and shows UI like [this one](https://www.movilzona.es/app/uploads/2016/04/Android-N-1.jpg)? If yes, you can simply disable (if rooted) or uninstall the package `com.android.documentsui` (named Files in App list). You than would be able to use a third-party document/file picker.

Comment: The default file manager app is a system app (if we are talking about the same app), therefore a replacement can only be an app from your manufacturer.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210168/218526

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. @Firelord I wasn't thinking about Doc Provider, but thanks for bringing that up, it might work as an alternative!