# Cannot open PDF files received on WhatsApp directly

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, pdf

When I try opening a PDF file that I receive on WhatsApp directly by clicking on the WhatsApp message, I get the message, "You may not have a proper app for viewing this content".

I already have PDF viewers installed on the phone (Google PDF Viewer, Adobe Acrobat Reader). I can open the file when I open it via a file manager.

How can I open the PDF files by clicking directly on the WhatsApp message?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate to understand how WhatsApp works: [Why WhatsApp is suddenly unable to open any APK shared by users?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203835/44325)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the trouble was that .PDF was in caps.

Comment: Hello TrueUser. How did you reach this conclusion that all uppercase alphabets in the file name causes the issue you described in your question?