# Can't open PDFs (and other files) from WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, pdf, attachments

I'm using a Xiaomi MI 9 SE phone (Android v11, MIUI Global v12.5.1). For quite a long time now, I've had the problem of not being able to open PDF files attached to WhatsApp messages I receive. When I double-click them, the app I choose either  shows nothing, or immediately quits (depends on the app).

I tried to check the app permissions, and there are no permissions - that I know off - that WhatsApp is missing. I also tried updating WhatsApp, which didn't help.

I do not have this problem with other messaging applications, e.g. Telegram. Also, the different viewers / handling apps are able to open PDFs from other sources.

What's the cause of this problem, and what can I do about it?

<sub>Note: My situation is not the same as in [Cannot open PDF files received on WhatsApp directly](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226530/142320), where the user was getting an error message about not having the appropriate app for the content type.</sub>

Comment: There's a similar question on [Cannot open PDF files received on WhatsApp directly](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226530/44325) though I'm not sure if the only answer is correct or not.

Comment: @AndrewT.: The title is similar, but the question is not, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer eluded me for many months, and then somehow I stumbleds upon it in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/miui/comments/q4opm4/pdf_not_opening_from_any_app/)...

**Just (re-)enable MIUI Optimizations.**

To be honest, there's probably some kind of bug in MIUI in the no-optimizations situation, where it mis-handles handing off PDFs and other files from one application to another, so that's more of a workaround than a proper solution. But - it works. You'll notice that the dialog you get when you click a PDF file is different than before, and if you select an app (possibly via a '...' button) - it will actually open the PDF.