# PGN file cannot be opened when sent using WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, share-menu

I play chess quite every weekend. After the game, I enter my game moves into [Analyze This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis), and see my errors. Then, I save a [PGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) file into my Android phone.

Then, I have 2 ways to share it :

1. I send the PGN file "attached" to an email, and *all* my colleagues that receive it
   can re-play it on their "Analyze This" app, clicking on the attached file.
2. I send it using "WhatsApp" - no way they can play it (even me !) -
   "You may not have a proper app for viewing this content" is the error message.

Analyze This is v5.4.8. Android is version 11.

Any clue?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate to understand how WhatsApp works: [Why WhatsApp is suddenly unable to open any APK shared by users?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203835/44325)

Comment: no, it is not the same

Comment: i can run the APP if I find the file from FileManager, but not if I click on the PGN file in WhatsApp, so it seems related to WhatsApp and not to APK nor Android