# this isn't a supported file type - Images, movies, pdf files, voice messages cannot be opened after a while

Tags: files, virus

A friend has a Nokia 7.2 (updated to Android 11) which has a problem opening images, movies, pdf files. When she makes or receives a photo or movie, she can open it normally, but after a while she gets the following message: this isn't a supported file type. So it looks like an app scans the system for media, then does something to it so it can't be viewed again.

She did a factory reset, but the problem persists.

Do you have any ideas how this works? Is this a virus? Did it infect the factory-image? How can this be fixed?

Comment: This depends on the apps. For example, [WhatsApp cannot open APK files](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203835/44325), thus they need to be opened from another app (e.g. file managers). Might help to mention which apps have this problem.

Comment: All apps have this problem. It has nothing to do with APK files, only media like photos, videos and pdf files.